# coercing columns of a data frame to numeric

Tags: r

I can't get the following formula to coerce selected columns of a data frame to numeric

```
x<-read.csv("more.csv",colClasses="character")

test<-list(more[,10],more[,11],more[,12])
test2<-lapply(test,as.numeric)
```

But

```
is.numeric(more[,10])
[1] FALSE
```

When I use the following formula it works:

```
more[,10]<-as.numeric(more[,10])

is.numeric(more[,10])
[1] TRUE
```

I can't make out the error in the first formula used.

Answer (score 1):

Because my work doesn't always necessarily use the same column locations, I personally would use a combination of josliber's approach and the original proposal. Create a vector of the column names you want to coerce, and use lapply to modify only those columns.

```
test <- as.vector(c("test1", "test2", "test3"))
more[test] = lapply(more[test], as.numeric)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When you use `test2 <- lapply(test, as.numeric)`, it is building a new list (called `test2`) with all the elements converted to be numeric. This does not change `test` and also does not change the data frame `more`.

You could convert columns 10, 11, and 12 to numeric in your data frame with something like:

```
more[,10:12] = as.numeric(more[,10:12])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `as.dataframe` if `as.numeric` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is `x` and the column name is "value" :

`x["value"] <- as.numeric(x[,"value"])`

My example won't work if you eliminate the "," in `x[,"value"]`.  I like this method due to its simplicity.